# Library Error while installing NPM on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, npm, ubuntu-22.04

I'm trying to install NPM on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS;

**How can I fix this problem?**

**Step 1:**

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update              
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                    
    Reading package lists... Done

user@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease                  
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
atenreiro@stellar:~$
```

**Step 2:**

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install npm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libssl-dev : Depends: libssl3 (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu1) but 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.6 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
user@ubuntu:~$
```

**Step 3:**

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install libssl3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libssl3 is already the newest version (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.6).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
user@ubuntu:~$
```

**Step 4:**

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt show libssl-dev -a
Package: libssl-dev
Version: 3.0.2-0ubuntu1
Priority: optional
Section: libdevel
Source: openssl
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian OpenSSL Team <pkg-openssl-devel@alioth-lists.debian.net>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 12.4 MB
Depends: libssl3 (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu1)
Suggests: libssl-doc
Conflicts: libssl1.0-dev
Homepage: https://www.openssl.org/
Download-Size: 2,372 kB
APT-Sources: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
Description: Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development files
 This package is part of the OpenSSL project's implementation of the SSL
 and TLS cryptographic protocols for secure communication over the
 Internet.
 .
 It contains development libraries, header files, and manpages for libssl
 and libcrypto.

user@ubuntu
```

**Step 5:**

```
user@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main universe restricted
user@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: Can you please show your sources.list? Only listed server on `apt update` seems somewhat little

Comment: Please also show the output of `apt show libssl-dev -a`.

Comment: output too long for this comment added as "step 4" to the original post above.

Comment: user@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                    
Hit:3 https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

Comment: Please edit all additional information into your question, as you already noticed it's unreadable in the comments.

Comment: And please show your sources.list file(s). Your question needs to be reproducible.

Comment: updated on step 1 and added step 5 with new info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the updates channel.

When I run `apt show libssl-dev -a` I get two versions of the package listed:

```
Package: libssl-dev
Version: 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.6
Depends: libssl3 (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.6)
APT-Sources: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages

Package: libssl-dev
Version: 3.0.2-0ubuntu1
Depends: libssl3 (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu1)
APT-Sources: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

(output reduced to the minimum for brevity)

As you can see, the the package version you are using is from the regular channel and the wanted version is from `jammy-updates`.

Add the channel to your `sources.list`:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main universe restricted
```

And while you are at it, you may also want to add `jammy-security`.

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main universe restricted
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate! I added the channel and now I've installed the NPM. Unfortunately, the jammy-security is giving me errors but at least I got to install the NPM.

Comment: The security channel uses a different URL.